Remove Items In Build history of Docker Desktop Using Command
In Windows Subsystem for Linux, I start up services using docker compose up -d. I can remove Docker containers using docker stop $(docker ps -q) and docker rm $(docker ps -a -q), images using docker rmi $(docker images -q), and volumes using docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q). I have tried removing items in the Build history of Docker Desktop using docker builder prune --all --force and docker buildx prune --all --force.
How do I remove items in the below Build history of Docker Desktop using a command?


I don't think that's exposed via an API

Thanks, Paolo. Is there a way to do this using native Linux commands?
